# Disable auto update at end of autoinstall/cloud-init

Tags: server, cloud-init, curtin, subiquity

I have a working cloud-init that is deployed using packer. Once the VM is booted and the autoinstall is completed, Ubuntu does the auto update thing. This seems to take forever to complete and is an unneeded step since we hand over to puppet after install.

At the moment, I pass incorrect DNS details to avoid the auto-update.

How can I disable that auto-update ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you add an answer explaining how you pass incorrect DNS details for the autoinstall?

Comment: @RetoHöhener - In my boot command I did this:

      "boot_command": [
        "<enter><enter><f6><esc><wait> ",
        "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
        "ip={{user `ip`}}::{{user `gateway`}}:{{user `k_subnet`}}:{{user `vm_name`}}:::127.0.0.1:127.0.0.1 --- autoinstall ...

This is from memory....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't disable it, so you're stuck with using a clever work-around.  I'd be tempted to use `cloud-init` to patch the subiquity code to skip the step.

From a developer

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250/226

> You can’t currently. Why do you want to install a system with known
> security vulnerabilities?
>
> You can probably work around this by not configuring the network
> during the install and dumping netplan into place with a late-command.

**edit**

I worked out a couple of methods to effectively skip the updates at the end of an autoinstall, but I have only tested with the 22.04 installer.  I shared my methods at https://askubuntu.com/a/1410679/376778

Comment: I've replied to that post, thanks for finding it. It did make me think, why do you need networking during the install ? I will see how much time I can get to work on this vs using the "wrong" DNS solution.

Comment: I wonder what he means by a 'late-command'. I've no idea how you could actually do that with packer. I'm wasting so much time with those updates, which I need to do at a much later stage.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether this is helpful, but I had a similar problem when setting up new VPS instances for Vultr.  The default cloud.ini configuration for Ubuntu servers on Vultr runs "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" on the first boot.  This was causing real problems with my setup scripts, which had trouble dealing with upgrades happening in the background.  As a result, I looked all over the Internet to find a way to shut down automatic upgrades on first boot of my VPS (and ran into this page several times), but did not find anything directly on point.

Ultimately, I figured out that the "user-data" feature of cloud.ini can be used to override the cloud.ini setup defaults, and I thought I would share my experience.

I set the contents of user-data to the following:

```
#cloud-config
package_update: false
package_upgrade: false
```

Vultr requires this to be passed to the Vultr API as a base64 one-liner, which comes out as follows:

```
I2Nsb3VkLWNvbmZpZwpwYWNrYWdlX3VwZGF0ZTogZmFsc2UKcGFja2FnZV91cGdyYWRlOiBmYWxzZQ==
```

This worked for setting up a new Ubuntu 20.04 VPS on Vultr.  Vultr no longer automatically runs updates or upgrades on first boot (allowing me to fine-tune how this is handled in my setup process).  For a stand-alone computer (e.g., a Raspberry Pi at home), it looks like the following website might explain how to inject a user-data file into a setup process that relies on an ISO:  https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/.  However, I have not actually tried that myself, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: So this works only with vultr I assume? It would be really interesting to see what the actual code behind this looks like.

Comment: I have used the same technique for Digitalocean and Upcloud.  For some reason, Linode does not support the user-data feature.  There are some differences between the different services in terms of how the #cloud-config code is injected.  Only Vultr requires the code to be converted to base64.  There were also some differences in terms of how carriage returns were handled.  No good documentation for these idiosyncrasies online, but it was possible to figure it out with a little experimentation.  Apologies for the delayed response.  I did not see your question until today.

Comment: Yeah, I think I tested this eventually and it didn't work in my case. It's all self-hosted, so no cloud provider.

Comment: I have not tried injecting user-data from a set-up of Ubuntu on a self-hosted server.  There are instructions for doing this when setting up with an ISO, but I have never done that myself.  I also found the actual documentation for the user-data feature in Ubuntu to be very confusing.  Sorry I could not be more help.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is indeed horrid. No worries, thanks for the exchange :)