# how to disable unattended-upgrades during autoinstall (user-data, cloud-config)

Tags: 20.04, user-data

Is there an option to suppress (or forward) the automatic unattended packages upgrade during autoinstall session? I do not want to download the huge data from internet site for each client when we have ubuntu mirror configured locally.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When you use autoinstall with the Ubuntu live server installer (*subiquity*) there is no built-in option to disable the package updates.  There is an `updates` key but the [only available options](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/a0e2e244bd3fb32430ea9f5fd2d3a5fe1b73f43c/subiquity/server/controllers/updates.py#L29) are `security` or `all`.

However, I have found a couple methods that will effectively skip the updates.  I have only tested these methods using the 22.04 installer.

**method 1**

This method uses [apt_preferences](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) to lower the priority of packages in the security repository.  This results in all packages in the security repository being ignored during the updates.  The apt_preferences configuration is deleted in `late-commands`.  The downside to this approach is that it is harder to install other apt_preferences.

Here is a snippet of the `user-data` file for this method.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  updates: security
  apt:
    preferences:
      - package: "*"
        pin: "release a=jammy-security"
        pin-priority: 200
  late-commands:
    - |
      rm /target/etc/apt/preferences.d/90curtin.pref
      true
```

**method 2**

This method configures `sources.list` without the security repository.  The result is that no packages from the security repository will be available and there will be no packages updated.  The downside is that the installation will not be configured with the security repository.

Here is a snippet of the `user-data` file for this method.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  updates: security
  apt:
    disable_suites: [security]
```

**alternate option to use your local mirror**

If you really just want to use your local mirror then you can configure apt to use it.  Here is a snippet of the `user-data` file configuring apt with a local mirror.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    primary:
    - arches:
      - default
      uri: http://YOURMIRROR
```

If the local mirror does not mirror all components and suites then the autoinstall may fail.  You may need to include `apt` keys like

```
    disable_components: [restricted,multiverse]
    disable_suites: [backports,security]
```

**see also**

- [Disable auto update at end of autoinstall/cloud-init](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290700/disable-auto-update-at-end-of-autoinstall-cloud-init)
- [Ubuntu 20.4 autoinstall user-data skip installing security updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390248/ubuntu-20-4-autoinstall-user-data-skip-installing-security-updates)

**notes**

I tested these configurations using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look in my answer -
https://askubuntu.com/a/1451620/1637750

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 and it works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1276420)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick to disable unattended packages upgrade by disable DNS.

```
autoinstall:
  apt:
    fallback: offline-install
  early-commands:
    - |
      echo $(dig +short geoip.ubuntu.com | grep -v '\.$' | head -1) geoip.ubuntu.com >>/etc/hosts
      sed -i '/^nameserver /d' /etc/resolv.conf
```

Only affects to the Installer live OS so it's safe.

But the installer needs to get `CountryCode` from https://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup and write into `/etc/apt/sources.list` to speedup apt package operation.

So we resolve the IP in early to make this feature work while DNS disabled.

Answer (score 0):

[Subiquity](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity) (the installer) uses [Curtin](https://github.com/canonical/curtin/), which in turn uses [`unattended-upgrades`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unattended-upgrades).
You can remove the package when creating your image:

```bash
sudo apt-get -y -qq remove unattended-upgrades
```

If needed, you can then reinstall it through a [late command](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#late-commands).