# Autoinstall local repository

Tags: apt, cloud-init, subiquity, curtin, autoinstall

I have my own ISO based on Ubuntu 22.04 that I generated myself. Here is my Autoinstall -

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: foo-ubuntu
    password: "ToReplace"
    username: abcabc
  source:
    id: ubuntu-server-minimal
  early-commands:
  - cat /cdrom/casper/install-sources.yaml | awk 'NR>1 && /^-/{exit};1' > /run/my-sources.yaml
  - mount -o ro,bind /run/my-sources.yaml /cdrom/casper/install-sources.yaml
  late-commands:
    - cp -r /cdrom/copy_to_iso/ /target/opt/
  user-data:
    runcmd:
      - |
        mkdir -vp /opt/INIT/
        mv -v /opt/copy_to_iso/upgrade_or_install_packages/ /opt/
        mv -v /opt/copy_to_iso/foo_installation/* /opt/INIT/ 
        mv -v /opt/copy_to_iso/abc_scripts /opt/abc_scripts
        rm -rvf /opt/copy_to_iso
        bash -x /opt/abc_scripts/copy_system_files.sh
        bash -x /opt/abc_scripts/setup_system_config.sh install_mode
```

During `early-commands` and `late-commands`, I have a local repository with all the needed packages under /cdrom/copy_to_iso/packages. During the `user-data` section, the location is /opt/packages.

When I install the ISO on a server **without** an internet connection, the installation ends perfectly well, and all the necessary packages are installed. On the other hand, when I install the ISO on a server **with** internet connection, I see in the logs that it found a more up-to-date package externally in the internet, and it makes the section of installing the packages from /opt/packages fail.

I saw some related questions on the internet, but I wish to make all the sections in autoinstall work **only** with my local repository. Here is something that I tried -

[how to disable unattended-upgrades during autoinstall (user-data, cloud-config)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410553/how-to-disable-unattended-upgrades-during-autoinstall-user-data-cloud-config/1410679#1410679)

Please look on "alternate option to use your local mirror". My problem is that I don't work with http in my local repository, but with "file".

I tried -

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
  disable_components: [restricted,multiverse]
  disable_suites: [backports,security]
    primary:
    - arches:
      - default
      uri: file:///cdrom/copy_to_iso/packages/
```

and also `file:/cdrom/copy_to_iso/packages/` - nothing works, and it still installs packages from external repositories.

How should I write it in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to disable auto updates by disabling network as a part of the autoinstall:

```
network:
  ethernets: {}
  version: 2
```

In `late-commands` I add the following content to `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` -

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
```

then I run `netplan apply` and my machine has network.

Comment: Hi! Would it be possible for you to post your user-data file? I'm getting errors in the autoinstall when it tries to set up SSH. Would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This autoinstall configuration might work for you

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    disable_components: [restricted,multiverse]
    disable_suites: [backports,security]
    primary:
    - arches:
      - amd64
      - i386
      uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches:
      - default
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
    preferences:
      - package: "*"
        pin: "release a=jammy-updates"
        pin-priority: 200
  late-commands:
    - |
      rm /target/etc/apt/preferences.d/90curtin.pref
      true
```

This will configure apt using a standard mirror without the given components and suites.

The `preferences` configuration will disable any updates.  More technically, packages from the `jammy` repository will be preferred over the packages from the `jammy-updates` repository.  This might prevent the problem of finding a more up-to-date package on the Internet.  The `late-commands` will delete this preference configuration so that it will only affect the installation.

It is hard to say how to use your custom repository without knowing more about it.  The `uri` looks reasonable, but even if it does work during installation the installed system will have a broken apt configuration because `/cdrom/copy_to_iso/packages` will not exist.  This could potentially be fixed with more `late-commands`.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me. It installed more up-to-date packages during the installation. Look at my answer, it fixed the issue I faced.