# Ubuntu 22.04 Autoinstall how to disable security Updates

Tags: pxe, cloud-init, autoinstall

I am setting up clients every now and then using pxe -> autoinstall
but after running the setup it takes very long to install the latest security updates.

I want them to install later not while the initial setup is running.
Sadly the official docs doesnt show how to disable this:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

I really need a way to make it.

Comment: I've not found a way to stop updating during install. I did, however, a find a way to create a race condition by trying that made things worse!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410553/how-to-disable-unattended-upgrades-during-autoinstall-user-data-cloud-config/1410679#1410679